# Is this question off-topic or is something else wrong with it?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41245/how-can-this-technical-message-be-made-clearer is getting silently down-voted, so I'd like some guidance on whether it is considered off-topic or something else is wrong.

It looks like it is better placed on writers.SE instead. Should I just delete my question, and repost over there, since I cannot migrate it myself?

Comment: fully migrated; I deleted the stub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question should be 'flag'ed as off-topic and a moderator will help get it migrated.